# Alternative to lexical_cast<T>(std::string)

Tags: c++, templates, boost, lexical-cast

I've got templated code that uses lexical_cast.

Now I want to remove all the lexical_cast calls (because it doesn't work well with /clr).

I need to cast object between std::string and their value.

So, the first direction is easy (T _from, std::string _to) :

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << _from;
_to =  os.str();
```

But I can't think of a way to do it generically from a string to any type (I need something generic that will work with templates, can't just use specializations for each type and use functions like `atoi`)

**Edit:**

Of course I've tried using the ostringstream in the opposite direction. I get this error:

error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::ostringstream'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lexical_cast` uses streaming in both directions, `<<` and `>>`. You could do the same:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << _from;
sstr >> _to;
```

Be sure to include sanity checks though.

Comment: Tried that of course... I get this error:  error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::ostringstream'

Comment: @Yochai You are trying to use an `ostringstream`! Of course, that only allows output streaming, not input streaming. Use a `stringstream` instead.

Comment: Lol, didn't event notice the o there... been looking at the code for too long. Thanks